# How do I find a tax advisor or "tax man"?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

Since I graduated college a few years ago, I've been giving a lot of thought to getting a "tax man" instead of doing taxes myself through TaxCut or TaxAct.com.  I'm not so much interested in having someone "do my taxes," but rather I'd like to sit down with someone who knows federal and state taxes really well and can help me **plan ahead** for filing my taxes during the upcoming year.

I read a [really good article](http://www.youneedabudget.com/2010/ignoring-your-single-largest-expense-is-folly/) about this a few days ago, but I don't know where to go to find someone to give me good advice.  I don't mind spending money on quality advice, but I want it to be **worth it**.  Any ideas on where to look?

Comment: thanks! I see my question is now sponsored by the **UNITED STATES**.  Whoah.  Joking aside, I'm curious as to other's success or failures in finding people to help them prepare taxes.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a bit of a shameless plug... but you could always check out the TaxQueries website.  The site is "similar" to this one but geared more towards accountants and tax preparers.

Looks around for someone who seems to know what they're talking about and check their bio.

If you're REALLY having a problem finding a good accountant, email me directly.  I have over 700 of them connected to my Linked-In profile. ;-)

Andrew Smith
andrew@taxqueries.com
http://www.taxqueries.com

Comment: I signed up for your site, but man, the captcha is killing me! How can I convince it that I'm not a robot?

Comment: The site is returning Server Not Found.  Last capture in the Wayback Machine is from October 2014.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would do some research online and try to find a CP. You could also ask your family and friends to see who they have to do their taxes. I don't like doing taxes myself, because I always feel like I am missing something that could be costing me money.

Comment: What does "CP" stand for?